# _triggers dataLayer variable blocks tag from firing

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm using Google Tag Manager to customise my GA setup, I'm reasonably experienced with the tool, but have been stumped by something today. Mysteriously a tag won't fire. It's set to fire on clicks to elements with a certain class like so:

[image]

After debugging I can see that it appears to be setup properly but the debugging screen shows a rule that isn't satisfied, but that I never set:

```
_triggers matches RegEx (^$|((^|,)1465634_100($|,)))
```

[image]

_triggers is a dataLayer variable that I can see is inserted in many tags that fire successfully.

What is it? And how do I stop it from blocking my tag?

Answer (score 0):

`_triggers` is an interval variable that you can't manipulate and is created implicitly in GTM (just like `_event` is). If you think everything is working, just that this `_trigger` is blocking your tag, then try to delete your trigger and recreating it. This resource might help out: https://plus.googleapis.com/108052589350497985004/posts/5k9UF6mz3kg?pid=6120479789651639250&oid=108052589350497985004

Answer (score 0):

It means that one of the trigger's enabling conditions did not pass for this event. Typically it's Check Validation, but it could also be the "Enable this trigger on" part.

reference https://support.google.com/tagmanager/thread/18705020?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by unchecking the checkbox `Wait for labels`:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix this by unchecking "Check Validation" on my trigger. This was a form submit trigger for my instance.